# Is it possible to create a smart contract that recieve a specific BEP20 token from an address, and send it back same amount of an ERC20 token?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, erc-20, tokens

Is it possible to create a smart contract that receive a specific BEP20 token named X, from a wallet address, and send it back the same amount of a specific ERC20 token named Y ?
of course the smart contract will have the supply of the token Y.

Is it doable ?

If yes, i would appreciate some hints.

If no, do you have another way to achieve the same result?

i would like to hear it.

I'm not asking about wrapped tokens or bridges, I want to delete an existing BEP20 token, and replace it with a total new ERC20 token, and instead of sending the holders their tokens manually from the new token, i want it to be done through a smart contract.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are referring to is a [Wrapped Token](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/what-are-wrapped-tokens).

Yes, it's doable.

There are many ways to implement a wrapped token, so I will not discuss them here. But you can take a look at different resources about it:

https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/what-are-wrapped-tokens

https://decrypt.co/resources/what-are-wrapped-tokens

https://consensys.net/blog/codefi/put-your-bitcoin-to-work-on-ethereum/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, again, but no i'm not asking about wrapped tokens or bridges, I want to delete an existing BEP20 token, and replace it with a total new ERC20 token, and instead of sending the holders their tokens manually from the new token, i want it to be done through a smart contract. Thank you for giving me your opinion on this matter.